# How do I make Chicken 65 crunchy?

Tags: indian-cuisine, deep-frying, chicken-breast

My older sister keeps telling me that the Chicken 65 she had at a restaurant had this crunchy taste and since I've made this recipe twice now: I've been unable to get that crunch. I believed that it was an issue with the flour I was using, but that doesn't seem to be the case? My first Chicken 65 recipe consisted of just using Corn Starch--at the time there was no Corn Flour available: the chicken after being deep-fried came out soft but not crunchy. On the second try, this time with Corn Flour mixed with Rice Flour and a tablespoon of Corn Starch: there still remains to be no crunch, only a soft coating. What ingredient am I missing to get that crunch?

Comment: Is your oil at proper frying temperature ? are you putting too many pieces in the oil at the same time ?

Comment: @Max I don't measure the frying temperature; I sprinkle some flour onto the oil to check if it's hot enough? I try not to overcrowd the pan: I leave space for each piece of meat.

Comment: What is chicken 65?

Comment: @GdD : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_65

Comment: Hi! What is known as corn flour around the world (yellow-coloured) is not called corn flour in India. Rather, cornstarch in India is referred to as corn flour. Also, the recipe usually calls for maida, i.e. refined wheat flour along with rice flour and cornflour (white-coloured stuff). Have you tried this variation?

Answer (score 1):

So, 2 things: First use rice flour instead of corn starch. Corn starch is mostly used in Indo-Chinese recipes. In Indian recipes like chili chicken, always fry chicken 65 in super hot oil. I am not sure if you make it with sauce or dry but if you are making it with sauce make sure you add chicken at very end.

For your reference you can see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DZtqRaHYsf8. The video is mostly in Hindi but you will get the steps precisely